# internal links b/w sheets of merged workbooks, using VBA (EXCEL MACROS)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

My aim is to merge all workbooks having multiple sheets from any specified folder to one workbook of multiple sheets. The problem is I don’t want external links to be maintained, If I use "breaklink" it will break all links(external links) b/w sheets of all workbooks. what I exactly I need is, After merging all sheets of workbooks in one workbook, I need links b/w these merged sheets.

***CODE FOR MERGE ALL WORKBOOKS INTO ONE WORKBOOK :***

````
Sub merge()

Dim FolderPath As String

Dim Filename As String

Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FolderPath = "C:\Users\Samiya jabbar\Desktop\test"

Filename = Dir(FolderPath)

Do While Filename <> ""

Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Next Sheet

Workbooks(Filename).Close

Filename = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```
````

Comment: "I need links b/w these merged sheets" - what does "b/w" mean? To me, that means "black and white", as in photography or TV. It's unclear - does this code actually do what you want it to do, or do you need help resolving a bug? If it's functional, what kind of review are you looking for? At a minimum, I'd _strongly_ recommend some indention to make the nesting levels more obvious.

Comment: The links between sheets within a single workbook are formatted as `<sheetname>!<range>`. When you merge/move/copy those sheets into a different workbook, the original workbook name is added `[<workbook>]<sheetname>!<range>`. So my recommendation is after you merge a set of sheets from a workbook, perform a find and replace on any formulas to remove the string between (and including) the square brackets.

Comment: Thanks, @FreeMan for your recommendation, b/w means between. I have got the answer now.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter T for your response. yes, hope this strategy will be worked fine. But I have got a simple solution, I am sharing here to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to open all files that are involved before you start moving.
Now move sheets (don't copy them), instead of `.copy`, use  `.move` .
Save your merged workbook.

***REVISED CODE FOR MERGE ALL WORKBOOKS INTO ONE WORKBOOK :***

````
Sub merge()

Dim FolderPath As String

Dim Filename As String

Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FolderPath = "C:\Users\Samiya jabbar\Desktop\test"

Filename = Dir(FolderPath)

Do While Filename <> ""

Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

Sheet.move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Next Sheet

Filename = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```
````

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of pointers:

- FolderPath should be a constant because it's value will never change
- Using a wildcard Filter with the path will ensure that you open the correct files
- Although ActiveWorkbook does the job, it is best to get in the habit of using qualified references
- `Workbook.Worksheets` returns a Worksheets Collection (not to be confused with a normal VBA Collection)
- Worksheets can be used to perform group operations on all of it's Worksheets at one time
- Download [RubberDuck](https://rubberduckvba.com/).  Among its many great features is Code Indentation.  It will save you a ton of time reformatting and show you unclosed code blocks

---

```
Sub merge()
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\Samiya jabbar\Desktop\test"
    Const Pattern As String = "*.xl*"
    
    Dim Filename As String

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & Pattern)

    Do While Filename <> ""

        Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True).Worksheets.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

        Filename = Dir()

    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```